# Is it possible to create different timeline for each Resource group in telerik scheduler?

Tags: telerik, telerik-scheduler

Is it possible to add different timeline for each resource group in telerik scheduler?

I have used resource to group doctors.

I am getting only single timeline for both of the group.

In following way-->

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I doubt it is possible - you can have a single timeline only, I think.